# Strider Build with JsHint reports 'Not a pull request. Skipping JSHint'

Tags: javascript, github, jshint, continuous-delivery

I have a build in Strider and have just integrated JsHint inot the build.

When running the build Strider reports 'Not a pull request. Skipping JSHint'

Any ideas on what could be causing this message?

Thanks,

Nick